# ng-view - how to disable re-init of pages

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I'm writing an angularjs 1.5.0-rc0 application with angular-route.

Each page in the view is related to another, which means in one tab I start a process, and in another tab I go to view the statistics of the process.

the problem that I'm having is that once I switch tabs, the controller is re-initializing the data and everything is reset.

my ng-view is configured with the following code:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/index.html',
            controller: 'IndexController',
            controllerAs: 'index'
        })
        .when('/update-flows-rarities',{
            templateUrl: 'templates/update-flows-rarities.html',
            controller: 'UpdateFlowsRaritiesController',
            controllerAs: 'updateFlowsRarities'
        })
        .when('/run-flow',{
            templateUrl: 'templates/run-flow.html',
            controller: 'RunFlowController',
            controllerAs: 'runFlow'
        })
        .when('/system-stats',{
            templateUrl: 'templates/system-stats.html',
            controller: 'SystemStatsController',
            controllerAs:'systemStats'
        })
        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});

});
```

I don't have any other relevant code to paste since it's a generic question, any information regarding the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why don't you think about creating `service` to preserving data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AngularJS, services are instantiated as singleton, So you can store data in them and access that data from your controllers.